# Label in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#writing introduction text
mn=tk.Label(window,text="WELCOME TO \n AAROGYA SETU \n SELF EXAMINATION FRONT",font=("Bookman old style",30,'bold','italic')).pack()


#linking sign up form
sig=tk.Label(window,text="click button to sign up",font=("Bookman old style",20,"bold")).pack()
```

Error message:

```
'Nonetype' has no attribute .grid()
```

I am unable to position my `label` (that I created using `Tkinter`) in my program. it doesn't take `.grid()` or `.place()` either.

What can be the possible reasons? my code execution otherwise is perfect.

Comment: Please share your code (and any error messages) so that we might be able to help you.

Comment: Your error message says that you are using grid, but the code says pack. Which are you using?

Comment: I don't see `.grid()` in your code - so using this code you could get this error. Always show code which generates error. And always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the most common mistake

```
variable = Widget().pack()
```

which assign `None` to `variable` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`.

You have to do it in two steps:

```
variable = Widget()
variable.pack()
```

---

But it seems you may create other problem.

`pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` are different layout managers and you shouldn't use two layout managers on one widget.

So use `pack()` OR `grid()` OR `place()`.

You don't need `pack()` if you want to use `grid()` or `place()`.

```
variable = Widget()
variable.grid()
```

or

```
variable = Widget()
variable.place(...)
```

or

```
variable = Widget()
variable.pack()
```

Comment: yes thank you! i changed to .grid() and .place() and things were fine! appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *


main = Tk()

name = Label(main,text="WELCOME TO \n AAROGYA SETU \n SELF EXAMINATION FRONT",font=("Bookman old style",30,'bold','italic'),bg="light blue").pack() 
#linking sign up form 
sign=Label(main,text="click button to sign up",font=("Bookman old style",20,"bold"),bg="light blue").pack()

main.mainloop()
```

this should work

Comment: At the moment `sign` will be set to `None` since the `.pack()` method will return zero. Generally bad practice to create and layout your widgets on the same line.

Comment: @scotty3785 though without .pack () my program anyways doesn't display anthing

Comment: @KavyaSingh Please share your code and any error messages